# How do i make a "back button" for bonitasoft 5.10

Tags: forms, button, back, bonita

For a school project i'am working with an older version of bonitasoft (5.10). I was wondering if i could make a "back" button to go back to a previous task/form. So the user can change the value in the widgets if necessary. Now i can only use the "submit" button which moves the user to the next task/activity

Answer (score 0):

In a BPMN process when you perform a task the process will automatically move to the next one(s) (you might have several outgoing transitions or using a gateway).

In Bonita, when you click on a button to submit a task it performs two operations:

- Send the form data to the Bonita Engine to save them
- Ask the Bonita Engine to execute the task and move to the next tasks

If under certain condition you want to loop back to a different task you can use an exclusive gateway that will lead to the previous task.

Here is an example: if you submit Step3 based on a condition that you can define on the transition that goes from Gateway2 to Gateway1 you will loop back to the previous task2
[image: Process example]